# Issue in add the product to cart when price field is empty

Tags: wordpress, price

I am using https://wisdmlabs.com/woocommerce-user-specific-pricing-extension/ plugin  in my site. Using this plugin i have add variations and price for each products. But i have one issue here. I can’t able to add the product to cart when the regular price field is empty.

[image: backend]

What can i do for this?

Comment: Hey, did you find something for this? I am facing this issue as well.